# How does allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor actually work?

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to add a new node into existing cluster and `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` is `2` for the current nodes but the default value from newly installed Cassandra is `3`. I was tried to find information about this configuration but can't find a clear description how this configuration is working.

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. I have cast a vote to have your post moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` works in much the same way as `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace` where it triggers an algorithm that attempts to choose tokens such that the load (data density) is balanced or optimised for the nodes in the local data centre.

The main difference is that `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` optimises the algorithm for a defined replication factor of 3 (default) instead of the replication factor for a given keyspace (`allocate_tokens_for_keyspace`).

`allocate_tokens_for_keyspace` was added in Cassandra 3.0 ([CASSANDRA-7032](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7032)) to improve token allocation for clusters configured with virtual nodes. However, it suffers from the problem where the replication factor of a keyspace cannot be used when adding a new DC since the keyspace is not replicated to the new DC yet.

Cassandra 4.0 solved this problem by allowing operators to specify the replication factor to be used for optimising the token allocation algorithm with `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` ([CASSANDRA-15260](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15260)).

In your case where the existing nodes have:

```
allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor: 2
```

a previous operator would have configured it that way because the application keyspace(s) had a replication factor of 2.

As a side note, thanks for bringing this to our attention. I have logged [CASSANDRA-17984](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17984) so we could improve the docs. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Does that mean I can set `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` to `3` for a new node in the same DC then update RF for keyspaces to `3`? My goal is I want to set RF to `3` so we can stop one node to do a maintenance because our application use `LOCAL_QUORUM`.

Comment: A friendly note to let you know that since that is a different question to what you originally asked, you should post a new question, preferably on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra where it's a better fit and I'd be happy to answer. Cheers!

Comment: Love this setting!  Allocate tokens for keyspace was a total “chicken-before-the-egg” problem.